# How to detect if a scrollbar is present using a @HostListener

Tags: angular, typescript

I've seen examples of `@HostListner` targeting different elements and events, I've even seen one listen for when the user scrolls.  Those examples look like this

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', [$event]) scrollFunction(event){/*do stuff*/};
```

So far what I'm trying to do looks like this.

```
@HostListener('???:???', [$event]) scrollXCheck(event){
    if(window.innerWidth > document.scrollWidth){/*do stuff*/};
}
```

the problem is, I don't know how to figure out what I should put in place of the `???:???` part.  I looked more into the syntax of `@HostListener` and didn't see many details on it because you can call pretty much any element or property you want.  Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Maybe `window:onload` ? You can add any javascript event which your target browsers support.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for the `onload` event and do something like:

```
@HostListener('window:onload', [$event]) hasScrollbar(event){
    if(window.innerWidth > document.documentElement.clientWidth){
        // Do stuff
    };
}
```

Another way to listen for events would be to use the `Observable.fromEvent` method, this will give you more control with the events in terms of `subscribing`, `mapping`, etc. Which would looks something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  Observable.fromEvent(window, 'onload').subscribe((event: any) => {
        if (window.innerWidth > document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
            // Do stuff
        }
    });
}
```

Both will yield similar results, just thought I'd throw this in as insight.